# dell inspiron 5593 - A computer screen pops up to the right and left sometimes

Tags: windows, google-chrome, laptop, dell-inspiron, zoom-meeting

I bought a dell computer for a week and a half, and I have a strange problem with the screen, I do not know how to explain it, half part of the screen, move right to left. I do not know what to do. I do not know where the problem is. How can I handle this?

This has happened to me 2 times, these two times I have divided the screen into 2 - one side was open Google Chrome browser and the other side was open zoom. Once I'm on 2 screens at the same time, it shows that the screen is moving.

For example, on the entire screen of a column that is even, move right to left

***update***

i also get a black screen right now.

Comment: Did you run an update since you bought it?  If not, try it.  If it doesn't help, take the Inspiron back.

Comment: thank you for help, yes i did update week ago. this is problem in the computer?

Comment: Unless you are using an external display which you forgot to mention?

Comment: No, I only use external headphones, I do not know if it is related

Comment: Unless they're so loud you go cross-eyed?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your intent, please explain to me again

Comment: That was meant as a joke.  I did not take your "I do not know if it is related" seriously.